# How to get a list of all the functions called in chronological order?

Tags: linux, macos, performance-testing, perf, compiler-specific

Is there a way to list all the functions called while executing a program in chronological order? Using the chronological list of invoked functions, order file can be generated. I can do this with program instrumentation ([-finstrument-function-entry-bare](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)) but that is too heavy for my use case. Are there tracing tools that can help with this on linux machines? I know [dtrace](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dtrace) has some capabilities but that is available on Mac OS only AFAICT.

Comment: See strace on Linux